# Is it still possible to reach call stack depth 1024?

Tags: evm, call-depth-attacks

In the past it was possible to reach call stack depth 1024 in EVM. However I heard that now it is impossible due to gas costs.

Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to reach callstack depth 1024, because the max forwarded gas is always 63/64 of the total available gas. The block gas limits need to be of the order of 1e8 ((63/64)^1024) in order to reach this depth.

Comment: Interesting! So the current block gas limit of 15M (1.5e7) implies that the callstack has depth at most 821.